# Returning a PartialView with C# Razor Pages is causing an Error: Multiple constructors

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying for hours to return a Table as PartialView with the help of C# Razor Pages.
First i got the error the returning model is not equal to the expected model.
I changed the view model and the error was gone.
Now i got the Error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DantronikOrganizer.Data.Models.UserVacationEntity]'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
```

I start from the beginning:
I created a Index Page to show users there vacation requests in a table, but if they choose to delete an entry from the table, the entire page would be reloaded. So i though why not using ajax to solve this problem.

I deleted the table in my index page and created a new one in a _TableView.
Now an ajax request should load the view from _TableView into my index page.
Now when a user is deleted an entry from the table, only the table would be reloaded.
Thanks to the new PartialView.

I asked ChatGPT a lot about my problem, but even ChatGPT is not understanding why i get this error.

## My Index View

```
@page
@model DantronikOrganizer.Pages.Vacation.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Urlaubsanträge";
}

<h1>Übersicht - Urlaubsanträge</h1>
<hr />

<p>
    <a class="btn btn-success" asp-page="VacationRequest">Urlaub beantragen</a>
</p>

<form>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 w-25">
        <input id="yearFilter" asp-for="@Model.FilterYear" class="form-control" placeholder="Nach Jahr filtern" aria-label="Filer by Year" aria-describedby="btnFilter">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="btnFilter">Filtern</button>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.FilterYear" class="text-danger"></span>
    <div class="form-check mb-2">
        <input id="approvedFilter" asp-for="@Model.FilterIsApproved" class="form-check-input" />
        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.FilterIsApproved"></label>
    </div>
</form>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h6>Ausgewähltes Jahr: </h6>
        <span class="text-primary">Urlaubstage: | Bisher genutzte: | Verfügbare: </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="partialViewContainer"></div>

<!--Modal Window to delete an entry in the table-->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Eintrag löschen</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Möchten Sie wirklich den Eintrag löschen?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="deleteButton">Löschen</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function showToast(message) {
            Toastify({
                text: message,
                duration: 5000,
                gravity: "top",
                position: "center",
                style: {
                    background: "#ff5722"
                },
                stopOnFocus: true
            }).showToast();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadPartialView();
            $('#yearFilter, #approvedFilter').change(function () {
                loadPartialView();
            });
        });

        function loadPartialView() {
            var year = $('#yearFilter').val();
            var isApproved = $('#approvedFilter').is(':checked') || false;
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Page("/Vacation/_TableView", "TableView")',
                data: { year: year, isApproved: isApproved },
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function deleteVacation(id) {
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
            $('#deleteButton').on('click', function () {
                if (confirm("Möchten Sie wirklich den Eintrag löschen?")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Vacation/Delete?handler=delete",
                        data: { id: id, __RequestVerificationToken: token },
                        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": token },
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.success) {
                                showToast(response.message);
                                loadPartialView();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            if (response.error) {
                                showToast(response.message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

## My PartialView Controller

```
using DantronikOrganizer.Areas.Identity.Data;
using DantronikOrganizer.Data.Interfaces;
using DantronikOrganizer.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DantronikOrganizer.Pages.Vacation
{
    public class _TableView : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IUserVacation _service;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        public List<UserVacationEntity> UserVacationList { get; set; }
        public _TableView(IUserVacation service, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _service = service;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetTableView(int year, bool isApproved)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            UserVacationList = await _service.GetUserVacationByUser(user.Id);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year.ToString()))
            {
                UserVacationList = UserVacationList.Where(u => u.DtFrom.Year == year).ToList();
            }

            if (isApproved)
            {
                UserVacationList = UserVacationList.Where(x => x.IsApproved).ToList();
            }
            return Partial("_TableView", UserVacationList);
        }
    }
}
```

## My Partial View

```
@page
@model List<DantronikOrganizer.Data.Models.UserVacationEntity>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[0].DtFrom)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[0].DtUntil)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[0].DaysRequested)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m[0].IsApproved)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtFrom)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DtUntil)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DaysRequested)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsApproved)</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Bearbeiten</a> |
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteVacation(@item.Id)">Löschen</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">No vacation entries found.</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## UserVacationEntity

```
using DantronikOrganizer.Areas.Identity.Data;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DantronikOrganizer.Data.Models
{
    [Table(name: "UserVacations")]
    public class UserVacationEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Von")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime DtFrom { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Bis")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        public DateTime DtUntil { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Festgelegte Urlaubstage")]
        public double EntitledDays { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Resturlaubstage aus dem Vorjahr")]
        public double? RemDaysPastYear { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Bisher genutzte Urlaubstage")]
        public double DaysUsed { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Resturlaubstage")]
        public double RemainingDays { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Urlaubstage beantragt")]
        public double DaysRequested { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genehmigt")]
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Erstellt am")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Aktualisiert am")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Bearbeitet von")]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nutzer:in")]
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your DantronikOrganizer.Data.Models.UserVacationEntity ?
As the error says that there are two similar constructors, maybe it is just confused about which one to use.

Comment: I expand my question with the UserVacationEntity

Comment: First of all use the controller convention on _TableView class as _TableViewController to follow the convention of controllers. and then in you ajax call you are calling "/Vacation/_TableView". My best guess is your route is not correct. Apply Route on top of controller to be sure.

Comment: Could you debug your code to check which step cause this error?

Comment: The Ajax Request is requested the Partial View, i can go with my debugger throw the partial view code after return Partial("_TableView", UserVacationList); the error is showing up

Comment: Sorry, i don't reproduce the error, could you upload your project to Github and share the link?

Comment: You don't really need a partial view to do this...  just use a standard razor page that returns a Page object.  Your ajax is updating the DOM. (as far as I know partials don't have controllers... but share the model of the page they are included in.  They are for breaking up large views into smaller more maintainable pieces...)